# Cómo detectar cuando el usuario cambia de pagina en ViewPager Android

Tags: android

Buenas tardes chicos, quisiera su colaboración en un proceso que deseo hacer, tengo un ViewPager y este tiene 8 páginas, cada una de estas tiene un formulario distinto y antes de que el usuario cambie de página debo validar que el formulario en que se encuentra esté completamente diligenciado, y si no está validado, informarle e impedirle el cambio de página, no sé como hacerlo y por eso recurro a ustedes, agradezco de ante mano vuestra colaboración.

Comment: estás usando un `Adapter` que extienda de `PageAdapter` o `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` ?

Comment: Si, creé una clase que extiende a PagerAdapter y posteriormente instancio el objeto con la clase personalizada

Comment: Pon el código de tu `Adapter`

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar esto necesitas usar el listener [OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html), evaluas si la posición anterior es diferente y determinas que cambio de página, este es un ejemplo:

```
private int positionanterior;

viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // dependiendo de la posición en el viewpager puedes determinar si cambio.
         if(positionanterior != position){
            // Cambio de pagina.
         }else{
            //No cambio.
         }
         positionanterior = position;
    }
});
```

Comment: Listo amigo, lo he implementado, muchas gracias, pero ahora quisiera en este mismo evento, evitar el cambio de pagina, he probado, pero siempre me sale error, gracias por tu ayuda